# How to perform a KSM full system scan

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, containers

I have multiple LXC containers run android N in my mobile phone, and I am trying to save some memory. After CONFIG_KSM is enabled, only ~9000 pages are sharing (sys/kernel/mm/ksm/pages_sharing). I have tried UKSM ([uksm-0.1.2.6-for-v4.1.patch](http://kerneldedup.org/download/uksm/0.1.2.6/uksm-0.1.2.6-for-v4.1.patch)) but somehow the result is even much worse.

So my questions are:

1. How to check how many pages are identical?
2. Can I mark all (or a lot of) process pages as "MERGEABLE" and do a KSM merge? How? In this case I think at least sharelib pages can be merged without modifying    any process source code?
3. Does UKSM work for android?

Thank you very much.

Comment: 1. Ksm will show you at stats (you mentioned) for all mergeble areas 2. No you should use madvise or patch kernel and set VM_MERGEBLE at all mmaps. 3. Why not?

Comment: Thank you very much, have you tried UKSM in android? Which patch on which version? Somehow it doesn't work well on my Android N (kernel-4.1.18).

Comment: No i didn't tried it

Comment: @Mark.Zhang there once third party port not maintained by kerneldedup.org for android. But now the website is down, I’m no longer finding them.